# Приоритет изменения строк в sed

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sed

Подскажите, как сделать в **sed** так, чтобы можно было изменить только одну строку по приоритету?

Даны строки:

```bsh
# param = 0
param = 1
# param = 2
```

**Задача**: Необходимо изменить строку с парметром `param`, но не изменять строки с комментариями в которых встречается вхождение искомого параметра. 
При этом, если параметр встречается только в комментарии, сразу после знака комментария, то изменить эту строку и остановится на этом, второй комментарий не изменять. Например, изменить с:

```bsh
# param = 0
# param = 2
```

на

```bsh
param = 1
# param = 2
```

Как-то нужно доработать вот это выражение:

```bsh
sed -E -e 's/^[ ]*[#]{0,1}[ ]*param[ ]*=.*/param = 1/'
```

Comment: У вас GNU sed?.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Наверное да, в Manjaro Linux

Comment: @Эдуард, да, не работает:
sed: -e expression #1, char 58: Invalid preceding regular expression

Comment: `sed -E '0,/^ *#? *param *=/s/^ *#? *param *=.*/param = 1/' file`? [Демо](https://ideone.com/AOAwhU)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, Не совсем то, что нужно. Изменяет первую найденную строку, а в этом случае, нужно вторую изменить, первая должна остаться комментарием: 
`echo -e "# param = 0 this is comment \nparam = 0" | sed -E -e '0,/^ *#? *param *=/s/^ *#? *param *=.*/param = 1/'`

Comment: Думаю, тут лучше воспользоваться `awk` или `perl`. Посмотрите [это демо](https://ideone.com/0HkU6o).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, `sed` обрабатывает данные построчно, т. е. все строки независимы. Помимо этого, он обрабатывает их за один проход, что означает, что даже при всём желании находясь на первом комментарии он не сможет узнать, есть ли где-то после него строка без комментария.

Что касается замены строки только не в комментарии, надо проверять на начало строки:

```
sed -r 's/^param = .*/param = 1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, GNU **sed** не имеет *look-ahead* или *look-behind* и в целом *PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)* для реализации задуманного.

Для реализации можно воспользоваться [вариантом](https://ideone.com/0HkU6o) на **perl** предложенным в комментарии к вопросу автором [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182013/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) (я немного упростил/модифицировал его вариант):

```bsh
echo -e "# param = 0 this is comment \nparam = 1\ntext....\n# param = 2\nparam = 3" | \
perl -0777pe 's/(?sm)(?(?=.*?^\h*param\h*=\N*).*?\K^\h*param\h*=\N*|.*?\K^\h*#\h*param\h*=\N*)/param = 100$1/'
```

Разберём подробнее "заклинающую строку" для **perl**:

- Указывается инструкция искомого на заменяемое:

  `s/что ищем/на что заменяем/`
- В начале регулярного выражения включаются модификаторы: **s** (single line), **m** (multiline):

  `(?sm)`
- Используется условие ([If-Then-Else Conditionals](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)) по шаблону `(?(?=regex)then|else)`:

  `(?(?=.*?^\h*param\h*=\N*).*?\K^\h*param\h*=\N*|.*?\K^\h*#+\h*param\h*=\N*)`

Потестировать можно [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/JEXzVH/4)

Аналогичный результат можно добиться следующим SH скриптом:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

grep -P '^\h*param\h*=\N*' testfile.txt > /dev/null && \
    sed -E 's/^[ \t]*param[ \t]*=.*/param = 100/' testfile.txt || \
    sed -E '1 s/^[ \t]*#+[ /t]*param[ \t]*=.*/param = 100/' testfile.txt
```

Который выдает время выполнения с помощью утилиты **time** на моей машине:

```
real    0m0,015s
user    0m0,012s
sys     0m0,004s
```

Сравним это со скриптом использующим **perl**:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

perl -0777pe 's/(?ms)(?(?=.*?^\h*param\h*=\N*).*?\K^\h*param\h*=\N*|.*?\K^\h*#+\h*param\h*=\N*)/param = 100$1/' testfile.txt
```

Время выполнения:

```
real    0m0,010s
user    0m0,009s
sys     0m0,001s
```

Выводы делайте сами!